# What happened to Google Calculator? It no longer seems to work

Tags: google-search, google-calculator

What happened to [Google Calculator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Search#Special_features)? It seems to have stopped working a few days ago.

Inputting

```
2 * 3
```

no longer returns `2 * 3 = 6`.

---

Platform: [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) 13.0.1 for Windows with [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) 2.4.8.

Comment: It seems to work for me on FireFox, even with NoScript on....

Answer (score 7):

#### Update

Observed on 2013-06-13: the calculator no longer requires JavaScript and more importantly copy-pasting the result now works again! (This works both with and without JavaScript from *google.com* blocked.)

---

Google Calculator now requires JavaScript. In particular, JavaScript must be allowed from `google.com`.

In the case of Firefox and NoScript, `google.com` may be blocked. To use Google Calculator, set NoScript to allow JavaScript from `google.com` (permanently or temporarily). Unfortunately, copy-pasting the result from this window does not work. Thanks, Google, for breaking the ability to use the clipboard for getting the result.

In the case of [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29), allow JavaScript in site preferences.

Comment: It's probably because the calculator was recently beefed up a bit, and given a UI.

Comment: More like broken badly and made unusable.

Comment: what's your problem with it?

Comment: @Louis: using the clipboard to get the result is now completely and utterly broken. Google Calculator has put us 20 years back in time, to the era of the physical calculator. We now again have to type the result in where it is needed.

Comment: I guess coming from the Bing calculator I never really noticed the shortcomings. I'm still not sure what you mean about the clipboard though. Was it bound to ctrl+v/ctrl+c before or something?